# A nonreflexive module isomorphic to its double dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, banach-spaces

I know that the definition of reflexive module is that the $R$-module $M$ should be isomomorphic to its double dual $M^{**}$ via the canonical map $M\rightarrow M^{**}$.

> I'd like to know an example of an $R$-module $M$ such that it's isomorphic to $M^{**}$ but the canonical map $M\rightarrow M^{**}$ is not an isomorphism. Do you have such an example?

(I know that for Banach spaces such example exists, but I don't know it.)

(I put also the tag banach-spaces, maybe it's helpful to know the example for Banach spaces.)

Comment: For Banach spaces, one example is James's Construction: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43986/are-there-non-reflexive-vector-spaces-isomorphic-to-their-bi-dual

Answer (score 3):

*This is a community wiki answer posted with the goal of getting this question off the unanswered list*

---

This question was crossposted to mathOverflow and received an answer there by GMark: https://mathoverflow.net/a/76019/19965

I'm reproducing the solution here, in case this link is somehow broken:

[image]